# Get all the visible text(Text, button label, drop down list, etc) from a page using JavaScript/Jquery into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to capture the visible text displayed on a webpage:

- Button labels
- Drop down list values
- Text
- Field labels,(Input box labels, radio button labels) etc
  Basically everything that is displayed on UI, I want to capture - Without HTML Tags.

By `tagName("body").getText()` will capture for single field.

I need for entire page, irrespective of ID/class assigned.

Comment: Only visible ones (i.e without the ones hidden by overflow) or everything.

Comment: Everything that there to display on the page. If page has tabs, than data for each tab is also to be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$("body:visible").child().each(function(i){
    //Here you can play with the elements as you want.
});
```

Comment: This will iterate over exactly one element (the body tag itself.)  I don't see how it solves the question asked at all.

Comment: Ok, edit now has it iterating over every direct child of the body.  Still not anywhere close to a solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) in order to target only text nodes, and extract their `textContent` property.

You would have to filter out nodes from `<script>` and `<style>` elements though, since I guess you don't want these (otherwise a simple `document.body.textContent` would do).

```js
function getDisplayedText(sourceElement) {
  // we need to filter out textContent of script and style elements
  var filterNodes = function(node) {
    var t = node.parentElement.tagName;
    if (t !== 'SCRIPT' && t !== 'STYLE')
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  };
  filterNodes.acceptNode = filterNodes; // IE doesn't like {acceptNode:...} object
  
  // input value hack
  document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="file"]):not([type="color"]):not([type="checkbox"])')
  .forEach(function(i){
    i.textContent = ''; // clean up previous calls?
    i.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.value))
  });
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    sourceElement, // walk from the sourceElement
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, // walk only through text nodes
    filterNodes,
    false
  );

  var str = ''; // will hold all our text nodes
  while (treeWalker.nextNode())
    str += treeWalker.currentNode.textContent;

  return str;
}
console.log(getDisplayedText(document.body));
```

```html
<!-- Dummy content -->
<div id="Content">
  <div id="Panes">
    <div>
      <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
      <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
        recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      var shoulNotBeInTheResult = this;
    </script>
    <div>
      <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
        here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div><br>
    <style>
      .shouldNotBeThereEither {}
    </style>
    <div>
      <h2>Gimme an <input type="text" value="Example"></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt sit amet arcu a mollis. Aliquam nunc nisl, aliquam sed consequat fermentum, pulvinar vitae risus. Nullam aliquam semper sodales. Vivamus dictum nisl risus, sed dignissim mauris
        accumsan et. Integer nec mi ipsum.</p>
      <p> Nullam volutpat tristique sapien, non rutrum dolor porta ut. Nam commodo ultricies magna non auctor. Aenean nec hendrerit libero. Sed scelerisque a dolor sed commodo. Vivamus maximus libero ut elementum viverra. Donec ut massa quam. Nullam vitae
        nisl libero. Nullam turpis odio, convallis lacinia leo quis, viverra lacinia lectus. Mauris id turpis consectetur leo ultrices cursus at sit amet sapien. Vestibulum convallis arcu ipsum, sed vulputate risus condimentum at.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. It works majorly. It fails to capture the label for => <input type="submit" value="Submit form">.   "Submit form" is not captured.

Comment: @Swapnil yes, this is not part of the page's text per se, it can't be selected, it's more like graphics. This code won't capture all `::before` or `::after`'s text `content` either, for the same reasons. Searching for it would make the code a lot slower.

Comment: @Swapnil ah sorry, I misread your comment... I though you talked about placeHolder. So for input **values**, we can append a textNode with this value inside teh input element. I added it to my answer.