# Best ways to check if an HTMLElement contains the value property

Tags: javascript, htmlelements

Imagine a function whose signature looks like:

```
function readElement(element: HTMLElement): string;
```

To implement the function you will have to check if the element is using the `value` property (i.e. `HTMLInputElement`) or the `textContent` property (i.e. `SpanElement`) and get the respective property. What I am asking is a couple of ways that can implement `readElement`, are foolproof and have high browser compatibility.

Here is a list of ways I've used to tackle the problem in the past:

- `element.value !== undefined`
- `element.constructor.hasOwnProperty("value")`
- `typeof element.value === "string"`
- `[HTMLInputElement, HTMLTextAreaElement,...].some(proto => element instanceof proto)`

Comment: `if ("value" in someElement) ...`

Comment: @AndréDS That will fail on `<input value="" />`.

Comment: @AndréDS — That's the point. `if(element.value)` will report *false* if it does have a value property that has a value which is an empty string.

Comment: Oh yes my bad @Quentin. I delete

Comment: Just a note, reading at the element level is a very bad idea for this function, go as deep as node level.

Comment: @Kaiido Well the aim of this is to change the text of an element, so i doubt that will be a problem

Comment: And what if your element is a div with some text nodes and an input  and a script or other non visible elements inside itself? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230366/3702797) is a more complete solution, while probably still not perfect.

Comment: @Kaiido Good point, didn't think that far. Though I've never had text-nodes and elements in the same element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if an object has a property, simply use `'prop' in obj`:

```js
[...document.body.querySelectorAll('*')].forEach((el)=> {
  console.log(el.tagName + ' contains: ' + readEl(el));
})

function readEl(el) {
  return 'value' in el ? el.value : el.textContent || false;
}
```

```html
<p>para</p>
<input value="input" />
<textarea>textarea</textarea>
<div>div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot that it will read the full prototype chain unlike `hasOwnProprty`

Comment: Which is why `hasOwnProperty`exists in the first place. **Own**

Comment: While this is a way i didn't think of I was hoping there also a way that doesn't involve checking for the value like `[HTMLInputElement, HTMLTextAreaElement,...].some(proto => element instanceof proto)` but without having to write every single element that has a value property

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you're saying. What exactly about the suggested Method does not suite your needs?

Comment: Well if elements like `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLTextAreaElement` implemented the same prototype rather than just directly implementing `HTMLElement` then we could had been able to do `element instanceof AbstractHTMLElementWithValue`